# xlwings Colab installation failure

Tags: python-3.x, pip, package, google-colaboratory, xlwings

When I do `!pip install xlwings -vvv` in Colab, I get the following. How to fix it?

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 153, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 382, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 201, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 365, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 313, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    req, self.session, self.finder, self.require_hashes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 224, in prepare_linked_requirement
    req, self.req_tracker, finder, self.build_isolation,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 49, in _get_prepared_distribution
    abstract_dist.prepare_distribution_metadata(finder, build_isolation)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/source/legacy.py", line 39, in prepare_distribution_metadata
    self.req.prepare_metadata()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 563, in prepare_metadata
    self.metadata_directory = metadata_generator(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/operations/generate_metadata.py", line 124, in _generate_metadata_legacy
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info',
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/subprocess.py", line 242, in call_subprocess
    raise InstallationError(exc_msg)
pip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From its [documentation](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/installation.html)

> xlwings requires an installation of Excel and therefore only works on Windows and macOS.

So, you cannot use xlwings with Google Colab.